# How to pull from a fellow developers repository using Mercurial

Tags: windows, mercurial

I'm trying to setup Mercurial on developer workstations so that they can pull from each other.
I don't want to push.

I know each workstation needs to run

```
hg serve
```

The format of the pull command is

```
hg pull ssh:[SOURCE]
```

What I'm having problem with is defining SOURCE, and any other permission issues.

I would believe that SOURCE ends with the name of the repository being pulled from. What I don't know is form the host name. Can I use IPs instead?

What permission issues do I need to look out for?

```
SOURCE == //<hostname>/<repository>
```

All developers or test stations are running Windows 7 or Windows XP.

I have searched for this answer and have come up empty. I did look at all the questions suggested by SO as I typed this question.

This is probably a simple Windows concept, but I'm not an expert in simple Windows concepts. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hg help urls` output has these examples:

```
Valid URLs are of the form:

  local/filesystem/path[#revision]
  file://local/filesystem/path[#revision]
  http://[user[:pass]@]host[:port]/[path][#revision]
  https://[user[:pass]@]host[:port]/[path][#revision]
  ssh://[user@]host[:port]/[path][#revision]
```

and a lot of info about what can be used for each component (`host` can be anything that your dns resolver resolves or a ipv4 or ipv6 address.  I beleive on windows systems UNC paths count.

Also, you appear to have some confusion about when you can use ssh.  You can use `ssh://` URLs to access repositories on the file systems of systems that are running ssh servers.  If they're running `hg serve` then you can access them using the `http://` URL that `hg serve` gives you when you start it.  It's usually used for quick "here grab this from me and see if you can tell me what I'm doing wrong" situations rather than for all-the-time sharing.